# Django on GAE and AWS RDS PostgreSQL

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, google-app-engine

Is it possible to use an AWS RDS PostgreSQL database with a Django app hosted on Google App Engine standard (Python 3)?

Currently, any code that tries to connect to the RDS database hangs, but I can connect to the RDS database from my machine.

Comment: There should be no problem, although the app should be really slow, as the app and db will reside in different locations.

Do you have security groups defined for your rds instance on aws? Maybe you added a rule that allowed connections from your local ip

Comment: The DB is set to accept public connections, for instance the app works okay from Heroku, and a Scaleway VPS. Also the RDS DB and GAE instance are both in North Virginia (us-east4 for GAE and us-east-1 for RDS), so quite fast.

Answer (score 0):

I would point out that that from the AWS RDS [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/es/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-connectivity-instance-subnet-vpc/) it’s mentioned that you can to allow access to the specific subnet (VPC) with “publicly available” to an IP Range, and you can get the App Engine ranges by performing nslookups as shown [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb#static-ip). Please keep into consideration that the IP ranges for the App Engine services change in a regular basis.

If you are not using VPCs then you should give a look to this [AWS doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithSecurityGroups.html#USER_WorkingWithSecurityGroups.Authorizing).

I would also suggest testing the connectivity to the GCP resources by using Compute Engine Virtual Machines, this can be performed also by using App Engine Flexible since you are able to [ssh](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/instances/ssh)  into the GCE VM instance.